# How to skip ads in youtube iOS app automatically when video is playing?

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube

We want to develop and iOS app which can be able to skip YouTube ads while YouTube video is playing in iOS APP. This app runs in background while video is playing. Our Android team develop this app because android gives them a system level permission to skip ads. Is there any OS level permission in iOS to skip ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don’t think that’s actually possible.

In order to have an app run in the background like that, you would probably have to be jailbroken or have root access. To skip a youtube ad as well as that, that sounds impossible, unless Youtube has some sort of system in place allowing other apps to add functionality to the Youtube app.

There are apps that connect with the Safari app and block certain things on webpages, but none skip youtube ads, they just block them.

With a jailbroken iOS device, I have seen many tweaks which do things similar to this, but I haven’t yet seen a tweak which actually skips the ad the way you want.
Considering this, your request may be impossible with the current nature of iOS.

Anybody please correct me if I’m wrong about any of this.